# C# return a random number twice in while loop

Tags: c#, random

Hey im trying to return a random number from a method. my code works, it returns a random number, but the problem is that its the same number it returns if i use it twice in the same while loop, how do i fix the problem? if there is a fix to the problem.

My code look like this

```
 private int ReturnARandomNumber(int min, int max)
 {
    var randomNumber = new Random();
    return randomNumber.Next(min, max);
 }
```

- Morten syhler

Comment: dont create a new random each time your call it.

Comment: Not always but when called fast enough.

Comment: you could make Random a static variable, so it will be used across instances, then the Random number will also be different in each of your class instances.

Answer (score 2):

You should move the declaration:

```
var randomNumber = new Random();
```

out of the method scope to the class scope:

```
var randomNumber = new Random();
private int ReturnARandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    return randomNumber.Next(min, max);
}
```

Comment: Wow quick respond thanks! it worked :)

Comment: You should explain why this works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new Random object each time. `Random` uses the current time as the default seed, and if you call that function often in a tight loop, it's getting the same seed value on subsequent calls. `Random` works best if you re-use the same object over a period of time:

```
private Random randomNumber = new Random();
private int ReturnARandomNumber(int min, int max)
{     
    return randomNumber.Next(min, max);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The seed used for the generation of random numbers is based for the current time. One way around that in your case is to let the `Random` be a parameter in the function, so that you can initialize it outside your loop.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to elaborate?